# How to pass unique incremental value every time when partial is called from the handlebar template

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I am using HandleBar Templates. I have a partial called "table". I am using this "partial" multiple time in my template to generate the dynamic table and rows.

I want to have a unique index for each row for each table. `@index` will not helpful as I need a unique key for other tables as well. For example:

```
Table 1

Index Name
----------
1     ABC
2     XYZ


Table 2
--------
Index Name
3     ABC
4     XYZ`


{{> table tableData=table1 cardinal=1}}

{{> table tableData=table2 cardinal=1}}
```

I tried incrementing the variable using this helper but it's value is not available to the next table.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("increment", function (value) {
     return parseInt(value) + 1;
});
```

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `increment` helper would suffice if you omitted the `value` parameter. The parameter is forcing your partials to know what the start number should be, but this is exactly the problem that has led you to create the helper - that your partials do not know the start number.

If you create a single variable to hold the increment count and have the helper increment this value and return it each time it is called, this will work just fine. The helper becomes:

```
let count = 0;
Handlebars.registerHelper("increment", function () {
     return ++count;
});
```

And it would be called from a template or partial simply like: `{{ increment }}`.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/d4m7eb6r/) for reference.

Comment: How can I reset this variable to zero again?

Comment: @HardikRaval: Under what condition(s) would you want to reset it?

Comment: I am generating a PDF using handlebar template, so each time I hit the end-point I am rendering content from the template.

So when I hit that endpoint again, I want to reset this variable. Right now it's keep increasing and never reset.

Comment: @HardikRaval: To be honest, I think that passing a `reset` argument to the helper is overly tricky and complicated. For your use-case, I think the best approach is _not_ to user a Helper, but to instead iterate over and assign to each row of each table an aggregate index. This would be done in the controller and the result would be passed to the template. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/rgdetaoc/